# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Error only occurs on mobile but works fine on PC?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am getting this particular error that only exists on mobile..
The idea of this function is that the user can convert one risk to another type of risk. The get method will get the ID of the first type of risk, then the target register.
Then the post will convert this risk into another type of risk.
This works fine on PC. However, on mobile I get this error and I just can't make sense of it.

Below is my routes.
[image]

And this is the error I am getting.
[image]

Can anyone help me understand why this error only occurs on mobile yet works perfectly on PC?
I'd expect it to work fine on both.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: As I see on screen, you call second POST route as GET request

Answer (score 0):

The GET route expects an id {register_id} which you're not providing in your url.